# Excluding a specific directory using a recursive 'ls'

Tags: find, ls, recursive

I've been using the following command to list the most recently updated files (recursively) within a specific directory and order by modification time:

```
$ stat --printf="%y %n\n" $(ls -tr $(find * -type f))
```

However, within the hierarchy, there is one directory that is full of files that get updated on a near minute-by-minute basis, that makes the above command near useless for finding files outside of the offending directory.

I tried using the `ls -I` flag but to no avail:

```
$ stat --printf="%y %n\n" $(ls -trI 'bad-dir' $(find * -type f))
```

Is there a simple way of excluding a single/specific directory using the `ls` command? Or should I be pushing the search into the `find` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need that extra `ls -tr`. This is equivalent to your command and faster:

```
find . -type f | xargs stat --printf="%y %n\n" | sort -n
```

Something like this will exclude a subdirectory of files:

```
find . -type f ! -path './directory/to/ignore/*' \
     | xargs stat --printf="%y %n\n" \
     | sort -n
```

This will still check every file, if you want to ignore an entire subdirectory use `-prune`. You'll have to reorder things slightly so that we don't find all the files first.

```
find . -path './directory/to/ignore' -prune -o -type f -print0 \
     | xargs -0 stat --printf="%y %n\n" \
     | sort -n
```

And in the interests in being as efficient as possible, the `stat` was redundant, given find is already accessing the file. So you're actually hitting the filesystem 2X with the `find ... | stat ...` approach so here's a more efficient method that has `find` doing all the work.

```
find . -path './directory/to/ignore' -prune -o -printf '%t %p\n' 
     | sort -n
```

To make this version work I've had to adapt the printf directives since `stat` and `find` use different ones for the various filesystem meta data.

#### References

- [find man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)
- [xargs man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)
- [sort man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)

Comment: If you think it's a good idea not to use `-print0` and `xargs -0` then you should at least check for a \n in the path.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer. The point @HaukeLaging brings up is important because you might have paths & files with spaces, which my original solution didn't handle. Using `-print0` and the `xargs -0` makes the boundary character a null character rather than a space. Did I explain your point acurately?

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't aware that `xargs` by default uses both blanks and newlines. And it makes little sense to use `-0` for `xargs` but not `--files0-from` with `sort`. And the big question is: Why use `stat` at all if the same `printf` possibilities are available in `find`?

Comment: If you use the `-print0` on `find`, you have to use the `-0` on xargs. I've added the example that @HaukeLaging was pushing for 8-).

Comment: Since you're piping it to `sort`, it still assumes that filenames don't contain newline characters.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
stat -c '%y %n' -- **/*~path/to/ignore/*(D.Om)
```